# What is the length of the 'description'/'name' properties for the 'Product' type in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am playing with Schema.org, creating extensions for Google Rich Snippets based on JSON-LD, using https://schema.org/Product.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Executive Anvil",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height.",
  "mpn": "925872",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  }
}
```

But I do not understand which how long the value for `description` and `name` can be. Seems to me that this is a very important value.

Answer (score 4):

The vocabulary Schema.org doesn’t restrict the length that [*Text*](http://schema.org/Text) values can have. Not for `Product` nor for any other type.

Consumers (like Google Search) might have their own rules/restrictions. These should, hopefully, be described in their documentation. For Google’s [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products), no restrictions are specified for `name`/`description`.

Answer (score 2):

google does not provide such information, but after many manual test the max length for `name` is 150 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Google indicates between >50 and <5000